# Git "cannot spawn interactive-rebase-tool" and "unable to start editor 'interactive-rebase-tool'" when running "rebase -i"

Tags: git, rebase

When running "git rebase -i" in git bash, no text editor window pops up and the following messages are produced

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn 
interactive-rebase-tool: No such file or directory

error: unable to start editor 'interactive-rebase-tool'
```

I'm using the default editor, Vim. Committing works fine so far.

The Git version is **2.40.0.windows.1** and the Windows OS version is **10.0.19045**.

I have tried searching for "interactive-rebase-tool", both for files on my hard drive and for information on the Internet, but to no avail. Rebooting and reinstalling Git didn't help, either.

Comment: I now seem to have this problem with my laptop. The OS version is 10.0.25314.

Comment: check your `git config`, and see if you have a setting which would indicate to start an editor named `interactive-rebase-tool` : `git config --list | grep interactive-rebase-tool`. (if you have this for `git rebase` and no issue with the editor started for `git commit`, it may be the `git config sequence.editor` setting)

Comment: if nothing show up here, check your environment: run `env` in git-bash, and check for variables starting with `GIT_` (`GIT_EDITOR` for example)

Comment: @LeGEC Thanks for your comment. It shows `sequence.editor=interactive-rebase-tool`, is this what I should expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checked your configuration, and it turns out you have the following setting:

```
$ git config --list | grep interactive-rebase-tool
sequence.editor=interactive-rebase-tool
```

This is the root cause of your issues: with this setting, `git` will try to launch a program named `interactive-rebase-tool` when you run `git rebase -i` -- and obviously you don't have one.

---

Remove this setting.

Check where this specific setting comes from:

```
git config --show-scope sequence.editor
```

The scope will probably say "local" or "global". To remove this setting :

```
# local:
git config --unset sequence.editor
# global:
git config --global --unset sequence.editor
```

(you can have a look at [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for extensive documentation on `git config`)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! It appears in the global setting, which should be reset in a reinstall process, I suppose. Do you have any idea why something like "interactive-rebase-tool" would be set?

Comment: @NoahTang: you don't need one, without the option git will open the regular text editor. If you have an install process that _forces_ you to set a value for sequence.editor, you may set it to your regular text editor (looks like `vim` in your case)

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to reinstall, as I've tried that before. What confuses me is that the installation itself sets the “interactive-rebase-tool”. I'm using the old good `vi` now :P

Comment: On my laptop, running `git diff` produces an error message like "cannot spawn delta", but I now know how to fix it. I'm still wondering why it happened, since I definitely didn't set that.